# How to put an excel formula to a dynamic range of cells using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and am using the following snippet to populate a range of cells with a vlookup function:

```
With wbk1.Sheets("classes") 
       .Range("AA2:AA" & .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C2,lookup!$A$2:$B$14,2,FALSE)" 'Actual vlookup
```

In order to make this dynamic, I want to replace the `.Range("AA2:AA" & .Range("C" & .Rows.Count)` part with a dynamic reference (in my case the first empty column in the same sheet).

First, I find the first empty column with this one-liner:

```
first_empty_column = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

However, when I do

```
With wbk1.Sheets("classes")
   .Range(ws.Cells(1, first_empty_column) & .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C2,lookup!$A$2:$B$14,2,FALSE)" 'Actual vlookup
```

I get "Runtime Error '1004': Application-defined an object-defined error.

**What is the syntax to define hard-coded ranges dynamically in this context?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following `Range reference` logic:

```
'PSEUDO-CODE
.Range(LeftTopCell, RightBottomCell)
```

where both `LeftTopCell` and `RightBottomCell` can be set with any valid range reference.
Moreover, you can not combine reference to range from two different sheets. You are referencing both `ws` and `Sheets("classes")` in single range reference.

Try with this:

```
With wbk1.Sheets("classes")

   .Range(.Cells(1, first_empty_column), _
          .Cells(.Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, first_empty_column)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C2,lookup!$A$2:$B$14,2,FALSE)" 'Actual vlookup

End With
```

Comment: works like a charm - many thanks - could you shorlty elaborate the use of ", _" in row 3 of your answer?

Comment: `underscore` just splits the long line of code into two lines. I used it here to improve readability of the code

Comment: It is actually `space` followed by `underscore`